# Text property of Listbox control returns string when nothing is selected

Tags: c#, listbox

listBox_groupmakingrepairs is a listbox control on my form. When first loading the form, nothing is selected in the listbox and the code in the following 'if' statement will run because the condition is true.

```
if (listBox_groupmakingrepairs.Text == "")
{
   Error = "You must indicate what group will be making the repairs.";
   Con = listBox_groupmakingrepairs;
}
```

But, if I run the following code...

```
listBox_groupmakingrepairs.Text = "Cell";
```

Followed by this code...

```
listBox_groupmakingrepairs.ClearSelected();
```

The listbox will not have anything selected, yet it will cause the first code snippet above to be false and not run the code in the 'if' block. When I step through and check the value of 'listBox_groupmakingrepairs.Text' it is "Cell". Yet on the form, the listbox clearly has nothing selected.

Am I using the Text property of the Listbox control incorrectly? Or is this a bug? Or am I missing something altogether obvious?

The way I see it I have a property (Text) that seems to work well most of the time. But under certain conditions it returns a value that isn't the correct value anymore. Why is the Text property returning an old value that has since changed? Does this make logical sense to anyone who can explain it to me?

Comment: Try using the `SelectedItem` property instead of `Text`. Ultimately though, maybe you need to be using a `ComboBox` instead of a `ListBox` if you want to limit the user to a single selection.

Comment: "maybe you need to be using a ComboBox instead of a ListBox if you want to limit the user to a single selection" -- I set SelectionMode to 'One' for the listbox so the user can only select one.

Comment: Then just use `SelectedItem` instead of `Text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I am a bit slow, but eventually I realized that Microsoft is the creator, so to them I will go for the answer.

Here is what I found:

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx), the following code I was using is a correct way of selecting text in a listbox control.

```
listBox_groupmakingrepairs.Text = "Cell";
```

Then, also according to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.clearselected(v=vs.110).aspx), the following code I was using is a correct way of deselecting all items in a listbox.

```
listBox_groupmakingrepairs.ClearSelected();
```

Finally, also according to Bill Gates (see two links above) the Text property is also a correct way to retrieve the text of the first selected item.

```
string SelectedText = listBox_groupmakingrepairs.Text;
```

But, as I described in my original question above, when I evaluated the Text property WHEN NOTHING WAS SELECTED IN THE LISTBOX, it contained text. But Microsoft says "this property returns the text of the first selected item." WHICH IS FALSE. It should have returned null because there was nothing selected...yet it returned text which was NOT SELECTED.

So to answer my two questions in my original post:

"Am I using the Text property of the Listbox control incorrectly?" -- The answer is YES.

"Or is this a bug?" -- Yes, it is.

Comment: Using the Text property of a ListBox doesn't really make sense, which is why the property is hidden in the designer — that's a hint that you aren't supposed to use it.  Stick with the SelectedXXX properties instead.

Comment: Using the Text property makes perfect sense because using it takes less code than any other approach...both in setting and getting the selected text value. You said "that's a hint that you aren't supposed to use it." -- where is that in the Microsoft documentation?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the **ListBox** control of C# winform control handles both the **Text** property and the **SelectedItem** separately, but in a way together.

It works in the following way:

```
IF [SelectedItem is True i.e. Item is selected] THEN
    Text property = SelectedItem.ToString()
ELSE IF [SelectedItem is False i.e. No Item is selected] THEN
    Text Property will still assume its current value (or in a way previous value) unless its manually reset
```

So always in such cases donot forget resetting the **Text** property. Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of how it works. But it still seems like strange behavior to me.  I guess I cannot see the logic in why it works that way.  Was hoping someone could explain it so it made good sense.

Comment: Hey if the answer was satisfactory, please accept the answer by clicking on the tick to left of the answer. And remember, you can accept only one answer. Or else you can even mention that the answer was useful.

Comment: You are setting the Text property to a value. From Microsoft's help: "When the value of this property is set to a string value, the ListBox searches for the item within the ListBox that matches the specified text and selects the item"